# Is it possible to disable bottom tab navigation considering redux state?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Considering the following application:

Shopping cart items, the user can have more than 1 cart and the application is divided with 3 screens.

1 Screen list of the cart items, he can add new carts / edit / delete carts.

2 Screen detail of the current carts that belongs to the user

3 Screen settings of the application

So basically I want to show the **Detail of the current cart** as the first screen.
Because is the most important use case for the user. (screen 2)

But in some cases the user did not even started to have a cart, so the most important, and then the most important use case is that the user should see the empty list of carts to add a new shopping cart (screen 1)

This would be a solution for the routing of this application.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import CartsListScreen from '../screens/CartsListScreen';
import CurrentCartScreen from '../screens/CurrentCartScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';

const config = Platform.select({
  web: { headerMode: 'screen' },
  default: {},
});

const CartsListStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    CartsList: CartsListScreen,
  },
  config
);

CartsListStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'CartsList',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  ),
};

CartsListStack.path = '';

const CurrentCartStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    CurrentCart: CurrentCartScreen,
  },
  config
);

CurrentCartStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'CurrentCart',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-link' : 'md-link'} />
  ),
};

CurrentCartStack.path = '';

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  config
);

SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-options' : 'md-options'} />
  ),
};

SettingsStack.path = '';

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  CartsListStack,
  CurrentCartStack,
  SettingsStack,
});

tabNavigator.path = '';

export default tabNavigator;
```

But as you can see the user here will always see the CartsListStack, and thats not good after the user already have a cart, I would like to take the user to the 2nd screen when a cart exist.

I could try to do this:

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  CurrentCartStack,
  CartsListStack,
  SettingsStack,
});
```

And in the current cart stack screen do:

```
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();

  if (carts.list.length === 0) {
    navigate('CartsList');
    return null;
  }
```

Then the user will be redirected to the carts list to add a new cart when there is no current cart to be shown.
But then the user can also click in the bottom tab to go to current cart, and nothing will be shown as a result of the *return null* of the code above.

**Is it possible to set a bottom tab navigation that takes the user to a certain tab, considering if there is a current cart in the redux state?**

**Is it possible to disable or even remove the bottom tab options, considering the current redux state?**

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible to do that.

1. You need to make your own custom bottom navigator using buttons so that you can use the `disabled` props which is available in them.
2. Map the particular screen with the store and state and based on the store state value use the disabled prop of the button.

Comment: Yesterday I stay a bit longer looking at this issue I had. I ended up doing a router switch navigator: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html , that contains 2 stack bottom navigators, one with the CurrentCartStack and another without it. So when the user does not have any cart, I navigate to one or the other navigation. But still the solution is not intuitive / natural enough... this is similar to the auth flow https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow-v3